# How to create a pointer to a Modifier

Tags: python, modifiers

I want to create a field where the user can select a modifier, usually I would use a pointer for this.
I can easily create a pointer to collections or objects like this:

```
bpy.types.Scene.chvi_dummy_obj = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type = bpy.types.Object)
```

But if I try to do the same with modifier like this:

```
bpy.types.Scene.chvi_dummy_mod = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type = bpy.types.Modifier)
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: PointerProperty(...) expected an RNA type derived from ID or ID Property Group

Is there a way to have a pointer to a modifier or it's just impossible?

Comment: Right now you're still trying to set the property on the `bpy.types.Scene` object. You would need to go the [types](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.html) docs and find the type of object you want to set the property for. In this case it looks like it would be `bpy.types.Modifier`.

Comment: Yes, it let me initialize the pointer on types.Modifier, but like this I have a pointer to a modifier on each modifier, and it's not what I want. I want this pointer to be on the scene, or on the object, or everywhere but in the modifier itself. 
Can you explain better why it's not possible to have the pointer anywhere and where (in the documentation) I can deduce what you told me?

Comment: I just noticed another issue with your code. You need to be using a [property group](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.PropertyGroup.html), not setting the type to `bpy.types.Modifier`.